# Can I configure IIS 7 Logging using Web.config?

Tags: logging, iis-7, web-config

I want to configure IIS 7 logging options (log file format, request fields included, log file rollover, etc.) using a site-level Web.config file. Is this possible? I assumed system.webServer/httpLogging would let me do what I need, but there are only two attributes available on that element and no child elements.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yep,

Here is a good example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347524.aspx

Comment: After following your link, it looks like logging can be configured per-site, but only in the machine-level ApplicationHost.config file--NOT in a Web.config file for a site. So I think the answer to my question is No.

Comment: If feature delegation is enabled in IIS you can set logging in web.config.